# Modify 'sources.list' file when upgrading Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, do-release-upgrade

I have Ubuntu 12.04 installed, and I want to upgrade it to 16.04. Unfortunately, both Ubuntu 12.04 and 14.04 distributions are obsolete, so I can't upgrade the system. The only way I found is to modify the `sources.list` file and run these commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
do-release-upgrade
```

Is this method safe? And are there any other alternatives, other than installing it with a CD?

Comment: That depends on what updates you do to sources.list. But changing repositories to `old-releases.ubuntu.com` should be safe. Also update / upgrade / do-release-upgrade is safe, and what you normally will do to upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> sudo apt-get update
> sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
> do-release-upgrade
> ```
>
> Is this method safe?

Sure, in that it will refuse to execute since it won't find the updates. You need to change the repositories to `old-releases.ubuntu.com` too.

Any upgrade can go wrong, regardless of this method. Nobody can predict a power outage. Like 1 of those 1000+ earthquakes California is getting hit with; if someone is in the middle of an upgrade it will go bad quickly.

> And are there any other alternatives, other than installing it with a CD?

Ubuntu does not fit on a CD so that would be a DVD.

- My favorite alternative method is to replace the hard disk, put the old one in a case,  mount it and then move files over from old to new disk.
- Install from USB
- Install from a partition; you put the ISO on a partition and tell grub to boot from there.

Regardless of what method you use you will have backups of anything important. As we all do.